# How do I find all solutions to sinh(1/z)=1?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I know that $\sinh(z) = (e^z - e^{-z})/2$ but I don't know how to adapt this for the argument $1/z$.

Am I right in assuming $\sinh(1/z) = (e^{1/z} - e^{-1/z})/2?$

Comment: It should be right to assume thing that way as $\frac1z$ is also another complex number, so the statement $\sinh(\frac1z)=\frac{e^\frac1z+e^{-\frac1z}}{2}$ hold for all nonzero $z$. And by doing so, the equation $\sinh(\frac1z)=1$ will be easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks, I just solved for that. Is it alright if I upload my work to be checked?

Comment: Of course you can, you are free to do so.

Comment: I'm skipping a few steps to condense the algebra but I've worked it down to 
w^2 - 2w -1 = 0 given w = exp(1/z) I ultimately solved this equation to obtain z = 
1/ln(1 + sqrt(2)), 1/ln(1 - sqrt(2)). This gives me one answer that's defined and in the unit circle. I think I overlooked something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $z=1/(\operatorname{arcsinh}1+2kπi)$?

Comment: I thought about that, too. I forgot about adding the +2k\pi 

The follow-up question was how many solutions are inside the unit circle so I backed away

Comment: Well, I get $\operatorname{arcsinh}1$ is approximately $0.88$.  So, none.

Comment: @ChrisCuster : Parentheses are missing : $z=1/(arcsinh(1)+2k\pi i)$. Quite a lot of them are inside the unit circle.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisCuster, I forgot about that lol

Comment: @Ayoub thanks for the correction

Comment: You can also write arcsinh in terms of logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u + iv = w = 1/z$.  Then solve for $w$ such that $\sinh(w) = 1$, and then solve for $z$.

Note that $\sinh(u + iv) = \sinh(u) \cos(v) + i \cosh(u) \sin(v)$.  As $\cosh(u)$ is strictly positive over the reals, this expression can only be real for $v = k \pi$ (any integral $k$, not just the evens).
This in turn requires that $\sinh(u) = \pm 1$ for even and odd $k$ respectively.

This gives you a solution set for $w$ of offset points on two vertical lines.  These extend infinitely.
$$
w = 
\begin{cases}
\operatorname{arsinh}(1) \pm k \pi i, &\text{for even } k\\
-\operatorname{arsinh}(1) \pm k \pi i, &\text{for odd } k
\end{cases}
$$
From these you can just take the inverse to get the set of points $z$ that solve the original equation.  Any of the $w$ points outside the unit circle will correspond to $z$ points inside the unit circle.

$$
z = 
\begin{cases}
(\operatorname{arsinh}(1) \pm k \pi i)^{-1}, &\text{for even } k\\
(-\operatorname{arsinh}(1) \pm k \pi i)^{-1}, &\text{for odd } k
\end{cases}
$$

As $\operatorname{arsinh(1)} \approx 0.88137$, all but the trivial solution are within the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\sinh\frac1z=i \sin\frac{-i}z=i \sin(-i\frac1z+2\pi k)=\sinh(\frac1z+i2\pi k)=1$$

Thus, $\frac1z+i2\pi k = \sinh^{-1}(1)$ and the solutions

$$z = \frac1{\sinh^{-1}(1)-i2\pi k}$$